# Calling JavaScript function from Python with js2py causes ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, referenceerror

I am trying to call a javascript function from python to change the DOM but I am unable to. Just console logging a message works, but as soon as I try to influence the DOM I get the error mentioned in the title. I'm sure there's something basic I'm missing here... Any suggestions or workarounds?

*app.py*

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/python_func')
def python_func():
    eval_res, jsFile = js2py.run_file('static/test.js')
    jsFile.hello()
    return "nothing"
```

*test.js*

```
function hello() {
    console.log("hello") <--- Works
    let div = document.createElement("div") <--- This doesn't
}
```

*script.js (this button calls python function)*

```
$(function() {
    $('#startbtn').bind('click', function() {
        $.getJSON('/python_func',
            function(data) {
        //do nothing
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Js2Py won't be able to run JS code that has DOM dependencies.

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py/issues/40